# Как получить Location?

Tags: android, location

Занимаюсь по учебнику "Android. Программирование для профессионалов" (3-е издание 2017 года), там есть такое место:

```
LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
    request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    request.setNumUpdates(1);
    request.setInterval(0);

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .requestLocationUpdates(mClient, request, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Got a fix: " + location);
                }
            });
```

Проблема в том, что после запуска, никакого сообщения с `Location` в логах не появляется. То есть в `onLocationChanged` программа не попадает вообще.

В [документации](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current), я нашёл такой вариант получения `Location`:

```
LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getContext())
            .getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Got a fix: " + location);
                }
            });
```

Но он возвращает `null`.

В чём может быть ошибка? Или можно как-то ещё получить `Location`?

Comment: Второе решение у меня начало работать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- В настоящее время `FusedLocationProvider` будет поддерживать фоновое получение геолокации, только если к нему подключен хотя бы один клиент. Как только первый клиент подключится, он сразу попытается найти местоположение. Если ваша `Activity` является первым клиентом, подключившимся, и вы сразу же вызываете `getLastLocation()` в `onConnected()`, может не хватить времени для входа получения первых данных о локации.

  `getLastLocation()` подходит для случаев, когда местоположение требуется немедленно или не может использоваться вообще. Если вы действительно хотите дождаться данных о геолокации, лучше использовать `requestLocationUpdates()` и ждать колбека. Если вам нужно только единичный запрос на геолокацию, вы можете указать это в `LocationRequest`, и запрос будет автоматически удален, как только появится ваше обновление.
- `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi` - если вы заглянете в код то увидете:

  ```
  /** @deprecated */
    @Deprecated
    public static final FusedLocationProviderApi FusedLocationApi;
  ```

  т.е. его так же не рекомендуется использовать.
- Если вы полезете в [документацию по Request location updates](https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates#java) там есть пример получения геолокации:

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      if (requestingLocationUpdates) {
          startLocationUpdates();
      }
  }

  private void startLocationUpdates() {
      fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
              locationCallback,
              Looper.getMainLooper());
  }
  ```

  Определение колбека получения геолокации:

  ```
  private LocationCallback locationCallback;

  // ...

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // ...
  locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
          if (locationResult == null) {
              return;
          }
          for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
              // Update UI with location data
              // ...
          }
      }
  };
  ```

Comment: Есть такая проблема, после запуска приложения, ответ на первый запрос координат может прийти через неопределённо долгое время, во все последующие разы всё происходит мгновенно. Причём второе решение из моего вопроса начало работать, и отклик происходит мгновенно. Не можете подсказать в чём может быть проблема?